# Why does my Tumblr search box turn up a blank page if there are no results?

Tags: forms, search, tags, tumblr, searchbar

I'm using a custom search box that searches tags instead of Tumblr's native search box. Here's the code:

```
<form class="sfm" onsubmit="return tagSearch(this)">
<input 
type="text" 
name="tag" 
value="{SearchQuery}"
placeholder="I'm looking for"  />

<input type="image" 
class="searchbutton" 
src="http://static.tumblr.com/mer0yol/3cjnot2ku/search.png" 
height="12px"
value="Search"/>

</form>
```

When you submit the search, if there are search results, it correctly lists them. However, if there are no search results, I get a blank page. Additionally, the SearchResults page does not include my messaging (but rather, just shows the tagged posts related to the search).

How can I show the {NoSearchResults} page instead? And how can I show the SearchResults messaging above the search results that do appear?

Here's the HTML for the 'search results' pages:

```
<div class="searchresults">

    {block:SearchPage}
       <p>Your search for "{SearchQuery}" found {SearchResultCount} listings.</p>
    {/block:SearchPage}


    {block:NoSearchResults}
        <p>Sorry, no listings are tagged with "{SearchQuery}."</p>
    {/block:NoSearchResults}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it all in the 'SearchPage' block and use 'SearchResults' and 'NoSearchResults' instead.

```
<div class="searchresults">

{block:SearchPage}

{block:SearchResults} 
   <p>Your search for "{SearchQuery}" found {SearchResultCount} listings.</p>
{/block:SearchResults} 


{block:NoSearchResults}
    <p>Sorry, no listings are tagged with "{SearchQuery}."</p>
{/block:NoSearchResults}

{/block:SearchPage}
```